# Sync a fork repo to an upstream without deleting the contents in the upstream

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, repo

I have a yaml pipeline that runs from an upstream to a fork repo but  anytime it runs it deletes files in the forked repo and replaces it with the files in the upstream. I tried adding a .gitignore file but it didn't work.

- git fetch
- git checkout main
- git merge upstream/main
- git push -f

Comment: Git isn't about *files*, but rather about *commits*. Nothing "deletes files" as long as you only *add* commits. If the new commits don't have the files, the old commits do. Make sure you don't discard commits; that's the only way to lose things.

Comment: Ok..But how would you sync a forked repo with a upstream without deleting files you added manually to the forked repo

Comment: Syncing a repository is about *adding commits to it*. Make sure you don't drop *old* commits when you do this, and you're all set. How you go about doing this is up to you and depends on the results you want: for instance, one way is to take the two repositories R and S, figure out which commits R has that S doesn't and put those in S, and figure out which commits S has that R doesn't and put those in R.

Comment: On the other hand, if R won't take new commits from S: figure out what commits R has that S doesn't, add those to S, and now S is a superset of R. If you don't control R and they (whoever does control R) are stubborn, this may be the best you can do.

Comment: And, remember this: checking out commit C1 populates your working tree with the files from C1. Switching from there to C2 removes the files from C1 and populates your working tree with the files from C2 instead. Switching to C3 removes the C2 files and puts in the C3 files. If C1 has only file f1, switching back to C1 removes all the C3 files and puts in f1. That's what it means to be about *commits*, not *files*.

Comment: What all this means to you, as an end user, is that you usually don't *just* want to "sync repositories". You usually want to first, sync the repositories (so that R and S both have ALL the commits) and then **make new commits** that *combine the work* in different previous commits.